# Rearranging a list of data

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I need  help for rearranging  my data

If I have data for 10 cases depends on L values (from 1 to 10) and every case has 5 columns (the first row has 5 values for L=1,  the second row is for L=2, and so on till L=10) and repeat these cases for every k values which are in the first column and they are 83 values, so for every ten cases the k value (first column) is the same.

If I need to arrange the data depend on k values instead of L values, so the first columns will be the different k values (83) repeating for every L.

I used the following code and it works only for the first case which is L=1, how I can use it for the remaining cases (L=2-10)??

```
tab;
part = -1;
Map[
  (part++; 
   pos = Ordering[#, 1]; 
   Flatten[{#[[pos]], part*10 + pos}]) &, 
  Partition[tab, 10]]
```

where `tab` is the list of data.

For example of tab {first ten cases}:-

```
 {{1.14342, -0.229913, 0.010659, 0.0106627, 0.0220835}, {1.14342, 
   0.056976, -3.4145*10^-6, -3.4142*10^-6, 2.8*10^-7}, {1.14342, 
   0.046243, -4.5741*10^-9, -4.5743*10^-9, 1.094*10^-11}, {1.14342, 
   0.026232, -1.8258*10^-8, -1.8258*10^-8, 1.0785*10^-12}, {1.14342, 
   0.00997399, -2.83587*10^-17, -2.83586*10^-17, 
   1.23384*10^-27}, {1.14342, 0.0000188759, 1.18276*10^-19, 
   1.18276*10^-19, -4.37444*10^-37}, {1.14342, 2.53853*10^-6, 
   3.61987*10^-23, 3.61987*10^-23, -5.51771*10^-44}, {1.14342, 
   3.33013*10^-7, 1.07414*10^-26, 
   1.07414*10^-26, -6.84044*10^-51}, {1.14342, 3.31144*10^-8, 
   3.13814*10^-30, 
   3.13814*10^-30, -8.37446*10^-58}, {1.14342, -6.17228*10^-9, 
   8.89034*10^-34, 8.89034*10^-34, -1.01556*10^-64},.....}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May we have an example of the data for tab?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added the first ten cases which their k values are the same after these another value of k that has different ten cases and so on. Hopefully, what I need is clear now.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal working example? As of now, it is very hard to understand what you want exactly.

Comment: Does this do what you want? `Flatten[Transpose[Partition[tab, 10], {2, 1, 3}], 1]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot march! Yes, it works:)